# Choose from multiple pages

Tags: php

I have a 'edit page' section on my site to edit a page, however It only edit's one page and I'd like it to edit a few (Options Menu that shows all the files of .html in that directory)

This is my code: http://newfoundfaggot.net/cms/code.tx
Sorry its not on the actual 'question' however I can't find how to post PHP code.

Any help is grateful..

Comment: paste your code and then highlight and press CTRL+K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$filename` could simply be an array instead of a string and you could then loop through each file in that array and perform the same function on each.

So something like:

```
$filenames = array('index.php', 'another.php');

foreach($filenames as $filename) {
   // Do what you're already doing here..
}
```

You must of course be aware of the security implications of letting your users generate their own PHP files on your server though!